# How to assign a value to a data.frame filtered by dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to modify a data.frame filtered by dplyr but I don't quite seem to grasp what I need to do. In the following example, I am trying to filter the data frame z and then assign a new value to the third column -- I give two examples, one with "9" and one with "NA".

```
require(dplyr)
z <- data.frame(w = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c"), x = 1:5, y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
z %>% filter(w == "a" & x == 2) %>% select(y) 
z %>% filter(w == "a" & x == 2) %>% select(y) <- 9 # Should be similar to z[z$w == "a" & z$ x == 2, 3] <- 9
z %>% filter(w == "a" & x == 3) %>% select(y) <- NA # Should be similar to z[z$w == "a" & z$ x == 3, 3] <- NA
```

Yet, it doesn't work: I get the following error message:

> "Error in z %>% filter(w == "a" & x == 3) %>% select(y) <- NA : impossible de trouver la fonction "%>%<-"

I know that I can use the old data.frame notation, but what would be the solution for dplyr?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `y` is a character column. What are you doing assigning `9` to it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Filtering will subset the data frame. If you want to keep the whole data frame, but modify part of it, you can, for example use `mutate` with `ifelse`. I've added `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your sample data so that `y` will be a character column.

```
z <- data.frame(w = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c"), x = 1:5, y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

z %>% mutate(y = ifelse(w=="a" & x==2, 9, y))
```

> ```
>   w x y
> 1 a 1 a
> 2 a 2 9
> 3 a 3 c
> 4 b 4 d
> 5 c 5 e
> ```

Or with `replace`:

```
z %>% mutate(y = replace(y, w=="a" & x==2, 9),
             y = replace(y, w=="a" & x==3, NA))
```

> ```
>   w x    y
> 1 a 1    a
> 2 a 2    9
> 3 a 3 <NA>
> 4 b 4    d
> 5 c 5    e
> ```

Comment: `replace` is a similar option that chains nicely: `z %>% mutate(y = y %>% replace(w=="a" & x==2, 9) %>% replace(w == "a" & x == 3, NA))`

Comment: You'll save a few characters by chaining instead of writing multiple `mutate` args (only need to write `y` twice, I mean, as in my comment), though it does mean building pipes inside pipes.

Comment: @Frank: I wouldn't have thought of using %>% inside a mutate function: bravo.

Comment: @eipi10: Thanks for the solution: elegant, clear (especially the version with replace(), thought the ifelse() is creative). It should be integrated somewhere in dplyr's standard documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It is my impression that the dplyr package is philosophically opposed to modifying your underlying data. You might find the data.table package friendlier for this operation:

```
library(data.table)
z <- data.table(w = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c"), x = 1:5, y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
m <- data.table(w = c("a","a"), x = c(2,3), new_y = c("9", NA))

z[m, y := new_y, on=c("w","x")]


   w x  y
1: a 1  a
2: a 2  9
3: a 3 NA
4: b 4  d
5: c 5  e
```

I'm sure there's a way in base R as well, but I don't know it. In particular, I can't get `merge` or `match` to do the job.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very creative appreach to the i[j] (I think) notation. Thanks for data.table: like many things in R, it looks so intuitive when others do it, yet so little when one has to figure it out... And yes, I agree with your comment about the philosophy of dplyr.

Comment: @user5 Yeah, I really like how the `X[Y]` notation for merging two data.tables mimics the `X[Y]` notation for subsetting two matrices in base R. I use this `X[Y, v := new_v]` "merge-assign" syntax all the time. If you're interested, the introductory vignettes are very clear: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started